# How to remove elements where specific values are repeating in array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [model_id] => 1
            [category_id] => 1
            [model_name] => Xperia
            [category_name] => Mobile
            [category_image] => 81649e37620644bec47244fda5233363.jpg
            [item_type] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [model_id] => 3
            [category_id] => 1
            [model_name] => HTC One
            [category_name] => Mobile
            [category_image] => 250a3e4655454feaec8e2537d149846a.jpg
            [item_type] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [model_id] => 9
            [category_id] => 3
            [model_name] => Apple TV
            [category_name] => Televisions
            [category_image] => no_image.jpg
            [item_type] => 1
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [model_id] => 4
            [category_id] => 2
            [model_name] => MacBook
            [category_name] => Laptop
            [category_image] => c9890535d26bd06189fc22940a5ee5da.jpg
            [item_type] => 1
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [model_id] => 2
            [category_id] => 1
            [model_name] => iPhone 7
            [category_name] => Mobile
            [category_image] => cab0631b071d0562412ccab2279d391e.jpg
            [item_type] => 1
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [model_id] => 5
            [category_id] => 3
            [model_name] => Samsung TV
            [category_name] => Televisions
            [category_image] => e60bd4822e516a93f1e99a8b456b70ce.jpg
            [item_type] => 1
        )
)
```

How do I remove elements where `category_id` as well as `item_type` are repeated ? With the code below, I could only remove elements where any single value is repeating.

```
foreach($all_device_categories as $arr){
    if(!isset($result[$arr->category_id])){
        $result[$arr->category_id] = $arr;
    }
}
```

Update: `category_id` as well as `item_type` should not be repeated at the same time. Its fine if `category_id` repeats but not `item_type` or vice versa.

Comment: What you really want? For both repeating? or individual catgory_id or item_type?

Comment: So yu want to match both keys?`category_id` & `item_type`?

Comment: @FrayneKonok see my update.

Comment: @RabinLama, Checked. But the confusion is if a category_id repeat but not the item_type then what to do?? Did you mean both the category_id and item_type repeat at a same time??

Comment: @FrayneKonok See my update again.

Comment: @RabinLama, Here is a question, Which value you will prefer then? Suppose: 3, 1: Apple TV and Samsung TV?

Comment: @FrayneKonok any is fine. Better, if random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you need to store only one value if both `category_id` and `item_type` repeats then you need to concat them using some other characters like: **-**. If you don't do it then some information will be missed out.

```
foreach($all_device_categories as $arr){
    $result[$arr->category_id.'-'.$arr->item_type] = $arr;        
}
```

I think this will help you, This will always takes the update array values if any match found. And if you don't want to take the updates value then simply you need to apply a condition before storing new array.

```
foreach($all_device_categories as $arr){
    if(!isset($result[$arr->category_id.'-'.$arr->item_type])){
        $result[$arr->category_id.'-'.$arr->item_type] = $arr;
    }
}
```

The second example will store only the first match, if the repeats comes then it will avoid.

Comment: Works nice. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

For multiple key match. You can combine those keys into array key. Try this:

```
foreach($all_device_categories as $arr){
    if(!isset($result[$arr->category_id.$arr->item_type])){
        $result[$arr->category_id.$arr->item_type] = $arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: You answer has a bug, suppose if `category_id` is 31 and `item_type`  is 1 then it will store first time, and again say `category_id` is 3 and `item_type` is 11 then what will happen in your current solution??